# Unable to bind data to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, data-binding

I am binding XML values to a DropDownList. Below is my code:

```
protected void LoadDropdown()
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.ReadXml (Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml"));

     DropDownList1.DataTextField = "country_Id";          
     DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
     DropDownList1.DataBind();
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem(" Select ","0"));
}
```

I want to get country names in the DropDownList, but I am getting id values like 0,1,2,3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying something else for the DataTextField:

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "country_Name"; //This value depends on what your XML structure is.
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "country_Id";
```

Comment: exactly i am having problem with the datatextfield as dataset is getting country_Id into this field and i want to display name instead..

Comment: my looks like this <countrys>
  <country>India
   <state>
     <text>Maharashtra</text>
     <text>Kashmir</text>
     <text>Goa</text>
   </state>
  </country>

Comment: Notice that I assigned `country_Id` to the `DataValueField` instead of the `DataTextField`.  `DataTextField` is what get's displayed and `DataValueField` is the value assigned in the HTML but not visible to the user of the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Items>
<Item ddlValue="1" ddlText="YourlistItem1" />
<Item ddlValue="2" ddlText="YourlistItem2" />
<Item ddlValue="3" ddlText="YourlistItem3" />
</Items>
```

your code behind for your dropdownlist should be

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ddlDataSource = new DataSet(); 
    ddlDataSource.ReadXml(MapPath("XmlFile.xml"));
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ddlDataSource;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my xml looks like this
  <country>India
   <state>
     <text>Maharashtra</text>
     <text>Kashmir</text>
     <text>Goa</text>
   </state>
  </country>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.

```
protected void LoadDropdown()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml"));
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select ", "0"));
    }
```